# Why can't I add my control bar to my panel

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

```
var panel:Panel = new Panel();
panel.title = source.displayValue + "-" + data.displayValue;
panel.percentWidth = 100;

var upButton:Button = new Button();
//  upButton.setStyle("icon", upIcon);

upButton.label="test";


var downButton:Button = new Button();
var closeButton:Button = new Button();

var controlBar:ControlBar = new ControlBar();
controlBar.addChild(upButton);
controlBar.addChild(downButton);
controlBar.addChild(closeButton);

controlBar.height = 50;

//panel.addChild(chart);
panel.addChild(controlBar);
```

I Have the above code, looking at all the examples I canf ind online I have done everything correctly, yet, i still dont have my control bar

when inspection the number of children each element has in eclipse, the control bar numChildren property goes up, but the panel doesn't so its as if its not getting added. Please help :|

Comment: Please provide some context.  What are you trying to do?  Where/when does that code run?  I'm pretty sure The ControlBar is a child of the Panel.  Adding Children to the ControlBar will not affect numChildren of the Panel.

Comment: After you call panel.addChild(controlBar), walk the control bar's components and check that it has the buttons you believe you added - and check their visibility and dimensions while you're at it. The might not be visible or of a visible width (since you don't appear to give them captions) unless you explicitly set those details.

Comment: the issue is the panel still has 0 children its as if the controlbar isnt being added for some reason. the control bar has (according to the count) all the children i expect it to have. all of this happens in the handle result fucntion of a HTTPService

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex 3 version of my previous answer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="vertical" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.containers.ControlBar;
            import mx.containers.Panel;
            import mx.containers.VBox;
            import mx.controls.Label;

            protected function button_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var panel:Panel = new Panel();
                panel.title = "Hello Panel";
                panel.percentWidth = 100;

                var upButton:Button = new Button();
                upButton.label="upButton";
                var downButton:Button = new Button();
                downButton.label="downButton";
                var closeButton:Button = new Button();
                closeButton.label="closeButton";

                var controlBar:ControlBar = new ControlBar();
                controlBar.addChild(upButton);
                controlBar.addChild(downButton);
                controlBar.addChild(closeButton);

                var vBox:VBox = new VBox();
                vBox.percentWidth = 100;
                vBox.height = 100;
                var lbl:Label = new Label();
                lbl.text = "This is content";
                vBox.addChild(lbl);
                panel.addChild(vBox);

                panel.addChild(controlBar);
                addChild(panel);
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:Button top="" label="createPanel" click="button_clickHandler(event)" />

</mx:Application>
```

Comment: what are you doing there that im not? (I have added a cption to all the buttons now)

Comment: I added a vBox as a content, so the panel can put the controlBar in its reserved place. Without content, the controlBar will be treated as content. Don't ask me why, I'm not coding in Flex 3 since long time, just wanted to help you with a working example. It works for me, does it work for you?

Comment: i have my chart as content though do i not? and no, still not working, sorry

Comment: You paste this code in a new application, run it, click on "createPanel" and you don't see the panel?

Comment: actually no, i dont see the control bar, and thats with out any special styling so nothing to do with that

Comment: although i feel dirty saying this, i am happy to not use a control bar if there is an easy, simple way to add the 3 buttons to the panel title bar?

Comment: You can see here that it works perfectly with the code I gave you http://www.adnandoric.com/_temp/panel/TestFlex3.html
You can see the source on right click.
I think your problem is something else.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using flex 4 you can just specify the controlBarContent property on the panel:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import spark.components.Panel;

            protected function button_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var panel:Panel = new Panel();
                panel.title = "Hello Panel";
                panel.percentWidth = 100;

                var upButton:Button = new Button();
                upButton.label="upButton";
                var downButton:Button = new Button();
                downButton.label="downButton";
                var closeButton:Button = new Button();
                closeButton.label="closeButton";

                panel.controlBarContent = [upButton, downButton, closeButton];
                addElement(panel);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Button label="createPanel" click="button_clickHandler(event)" />
</s:Application>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: alas, the customer has specified flex 3 as they have a VERY extensive style guide we have to follow that is written in flex 3 and no one has the time to convert it to flex 4 just yet :(

Comment: Just posted the Flex 3 answer, please tell me if it works for you.